# Ubutu 18.04 mkvirtualenv distutils.sysconfig problem

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv

I have a  problem with mkvirtualenv. When I try mkvirtualenv py39 --python=/usr/bin/python3.9 I get File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in import distutils.sysconfig ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig' .
Thanks

Comment: Python 3.6 (not 3.9) came with your install of Ubuntu 18.04. Using the wrong version of Python3 for system operations on an 18.04 system will break lots of things. You have encountered one symptom. Go back to 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

The one concern I have is that you appear to be running a version of python newer than what is shipped which could be causing the issues, but for a stock install the following steps should get it working for you.

Make sure you have installed the virtual tools

```
sudo apt install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Source the wrapper script

```
source '/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```

mkvirtualenv should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid response James. Unfortunately, the  install reports that  'virtualenvwrapper is already the newest version (4.3.1-2).' and sourcing it has no effect on the error message that mkvirtualenv reports. I have tried making a virtual environment for python3.9 with conda and this works, but some of the packages I need to install don't seem to have been updated yet and they won't install with conda

Comment: It seems that you are using Python Anaconda using Python 3.9.  According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/how-to-install-python3-9-with-conda) not all of the packages are updated yet which might be causing the issue.  The other thing I can think of is that you are using mkvirtualenv which is installed as part of the virtualenvwrapper tools, but they are independent of the Anaconda tools.  Instead you should use `conda create -n envname python=x.x anaconda` so that you are using the matching tooling.

Comment: Thanks James, I've had to go back to Pythgon3.8 for the time being with PyCHarm